# Error while installing Ubuntu Server, Install fails at 'Installing System: 33%'

Tags: server, partitioning, system-installation, hard-drive

I'm mostly a windows user, so please lay everything in layman's terms XD

I've been trying to install just about every ubuntu server version on my server, but they all fail at 'Installing System: 33%'. The drive I am using is 137.4gb so that shouldn't be a problem. this is also a particularly old system being a HP Proliant DL360 G4, with an IBM HDD (which I know you're not supposed to mix hdd manufacturers, but I'm on a budget here, I also really don't want to spend much on a deprecated server)

I have tried basically everything I can with this server, and have basically exhausted any idea I could think of. I've done basically every ubuntu server version (ubuntu server 12 and up, both in ISO and DD mode) and I've tried installing some other linux server distros with varying results, none of them have succeeded.

I'm pretty sure this is a HDD problem, but I can't do anything to check because I would need an OS to do that, and I don't have any other systems that use the U320 SCSI format of drive. It should also be noted this drive is in RAID 0 because I can't turn raid off (and it's hard-wired in, I can't remove the raid card) and I have no other drives in the system other than that one, I don't really know how raid works, but it might be the culprit.

I'm going to edit this to include the log file when I do CTRL+ALT+F4, but last time I checked the error was something about GRUB

Comment: You could have a faulty install media(like a corrupted iso, corruption during writing to the USB / DVD). It could also be a broken disc. But you can run a disc check without installing an OS. You just need a usb bootable OS.

Comment: I would try booting a desktop ISO (in live mode; and **not** GNOME!, I'd likely to have booted a xubuntu/lubuntu) to validate your SMART [drive] health. I have DL360/380's G3 & G4 so know it's possible (but haven't done it in years so can't tell you what releases I have booted).  Live server ISOs are available too.

Comment: Every time I've tried to use a desktop ISO it's said 'Cannot display this video mode' is there a known fix for this?

either way I'm going to be creating a lubuntu drive, and see if that'll boot properly

Comment: You haven't said what desktop you tried; Ubuntu (with unity/gnome have higher graphic requirements than servers usually have - thus video issues) - why I suggested Lubuntu/Xubuntu which have lower requirements - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements

Comment: I've used the standard Ubuntu Desktop 18. Now that i think of it I should've tried lubuntu first.

lubuntu is going to take about an hour, so I guess I'll report back when It's done

Comment: Which a server doesn't meet specs - thus issues as outlined in docs.  You can't use the onboard graphics as it doesn't have the ram for GNOME; so did you add a graphics card as required for your server to boot GNOME/Ubuntu 18.04 LTS  - why I suggested lighter desktops (which will work with inbuilt card ram)

Comment: I've got tons of gpus lying around, i could try one. I didn't really think I could use a bog standard gpu in a server

Comment: You'll likely have issues getting it to fit; using a lighter desktop as already stated in each of my comments is the easy fix; after all desktops on servers just waste resources .. you're better without any desktop.

Comment: Yeah, right now i just want to see if the hard drive works.
on another note i can't find any gpus that fit the server, so lubuntu it is.
and to be honest, at this point any os at all is a success, even if it's off a usb stick XD i've been trying to see anything other than an error screen for days now.

Comment: I keep getting a bunch of Buffer I/O errors and print_req errors on dev sr1, is this normal behavior?

Comment: Hmm it seems to be stuck on "[37.968575] Buffer I/O error on dev sr1, logical block 49147 async page read"

Comment: Okay so quick update
Lubuntu won't load for an unknown reason
Xubuntu gives me the video display error

Comment: Ah hah! Progress. The server thinks the hdd is busy, which is probably why any reading/writing to the disc results as an error